# Polyline width bigger than one point?

Tags: c++, graphics, windows-10, gdi

Is there any chance to set Polyline width bigger than the standard one point?

```
SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
SetDCPenColor(hdc, (255, 0, 0));
Polyline(hdc, apt, count);
```

Comment: Not with a stock pen. Check out CreatePen()

Comment: In win32 VCL encapsulation of GDI you can set `Canvas->Pen->Width=5` to render 5 pixel wide lines/polylines/... so in GDI should be something similar....

Comment: @HerrJoebob
Thank you, it works.
`SelectObject(hdc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 0, 255)));`

Comment: @Ziggi You might want to add that as an answer for others ... (and mention that it was Her Joebob's idea to use `CreatePen()`)  and as it works also accept it ...